# Grails Test Domain Model - Mocks

Tags: unit-testing, grails, testing

I am trying to test some methods within a Domain object, the code seems to execute (based on log) but the assertions fail.

**The code being tested (`extendDates`), is working, I am just adding the unit tests now.**
I assume I am doing something wrong in the mocking.The following is a simplified version of my code. Based on the log output, the assertion should pass.

```
class EventDate{
   Date startDate
   Date endDate
   belongsTo = [Appointments owner]
   static constraints = {
     endDate(nullable:true, blank:false)
     startDate(nullable:false, blank:false)
   }
}

class Appointments {
     hasMany = [ eventDates: EventDate]
     belongsTo = [ customer: Customer ] 

     def extendDates(start,end){
         //some logic on eventDates...
         EventDate(startDate:start,endDate:end, owner:this).save(flush:true,failOnError:true);
     }
}

@TestFor(Appointments)
@Mock([EventDate])
class AppointmentsTests {

    void testDateExtend(){
        assertTrue domain != null
        assertTrue domain instanceof Appointments

        //Log indicates the correct execution and creation of event
        domain.extendDates(new Date(),null)
        //following returns NullPointerException
        assertTrue domain.eventDates.size() == 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will get `NullPointerException` in the assert condition. The reason being that, you are creating instance of `EventDate` in the `extendDates` method but you are not really adding it to the `eventDates` list in `Appointments` domain.

So, you have to modify your that method something like:

```
// Initialize with empty array to avoid NPE
List<EventDate> eventDates = []

static hasMany = [ eventDates: EventDate]

def extendDates(start, end) {
     EventDate instance = EventDate(start, end).save()

     // And add it to the list of events
     this.addToEventDates(instance)
     this.save(flush: true)
 }
```

Now, your test case should work your assert condition.

(Also, looks like you have not added nullable constraint in `end` but passing the null value while creating instance of `EventDate`, may be not included in sample code)

Comment: Right, I apologize for these mistakes, should be copying code more carefully.  As I added in the description, the extendDates method has been manually tested and is working as expected.

Comment: Also, in the actual code there is no need to explicitly defying a list, just the association is working.

Comment: Right this is correct regardless. This issue just didnt pop up in my code. Guess the test served its purpose ^_^

Answer (score 3):

In your example you test for

```
if (create_new)
```

The variable "create_new" is never set and would therefore test false using groovy truth logic, thus never executing the if statement.

The if statement never adds anything to the "eventDates" property of Appointments, this would also mean that the assertion would fail.

I'm thinking your example is incomplete and therefore cannot help you until you expand it.